# Transpose Rows into Specific Generic Columns in Order

Tags: sql, sql-server, salesforce

I have a table that stores and ID and ethnicity information as followed:

[image]

The ethnicity data is unfortunately in a single column separated by semicolons.

I used the following to split out of the semicolons into rows and add id numbers to each row to make them easier to identify.

```sql
select row_number() over(order by salesforce_id) as rownum, x.salesforce_id, value 
from JRM_EXPORT_CONTACT x 
cross apply string_split(ipeds_ethnicities,';') group by SALESFORCE_ID, value
```

The data is at least now seperated out into individual rows.

[image]

However the problem I'm having now is how to take this information and put it into a table that would follow the format:

salesforce_id, race_1, race_2, race_3, race_4, race_5

I've tried using a `PIVOT` combiined with the `string_split` mentioned above, but this will generate columns based on the race names, and not into my generic columns.

Something like:

```sql
select *
from 
(
  select row_number() over(order by salesforce_id) id,  salesforce_id, value 
  from JRM_EXPORT_CONTACT 
  cross apply string_split(ipeds_ethnicities,';')
) src 
pivot(max(value) for value in ([African American], [American Indian or Alaska Native], [American Indian or Alaskan Native], ....[ETC]))p
```

I've also tried using a CTE and left outer joining several times, but the performance for that is very bad.

Is there a better way to transpose these columns in the order determined by the `row_number` I added in the first step?

Comment: I suggest a Cross Tab. What order are you after though; you're `ROW_NUMBER` expression is ordered on `salesforce_id`, however, after your split you'll have multiple instances of the same `salesforce_id`. Sample data expected results as formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements will help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
select ec.*
from JRM_EXPORT_CONTACT outer apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) as race_1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then value end) as race_2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then value end) as race_3,
             max(case when seqnum = 4 then value end) as race_4,
             max(case when seqnum = 5 then value end) as race_5                 
      from (select value, row_number() over (order by by (select null)) as seqnum
            from string_split(ec.ipeds_ethnicities, ';')
           ) e
     ) e
```

By doing the pivoting *within* each row rather than across all rows, you should see a performance improvement.

Note that `string_split()` does not guarantee the order of the rows being returned.  And `row_number()` doesn't guarantee keeping the rows in the right order.  If ordering is important, you can use the original string:

```
      from (select value,
                   row_number() over (order by charindex(';' + value + ';', ';' + ec.ipeds_ethnicities + ';')) as seqnum
            from string_split(ec.ipeds_ethnicities, ';')
           ) e
```